# How to run `x2goclient desktop session` with pyhoca-cli?

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, pyhoca-cli

I needed to run `x2goclient desktop session` on background. I found out that `x2goclient` cannot create new session, but user should use x2goclient GUI to create some sessions, then you can use command to use already created sessions. Found another CLI, called pyhoca-cli, which has a lot of advantages and it can create new sessions. But the problem is when it creates session, instead of showing x2goclient desktop windows, it shows x2goclient ssh terminal. I am using the commands like this:
`pyhoca-cli --new --server=some_ip --port=some_port --username=some_username`